Cannot use PySpark to fetch data from Postgres in Google Cloud Vertex AI
I cannot get data from Postgres into Jupyter Lab in Vertex AI with PySpark (i guess it fails to load the jdbc file but I don't know how to fix it)
I tried to retrieve some data from Postgresql using PySpark on Vertex AI Jupyter Lab
This is my code
#copy jar file
!gsutil cp gs://test_config_analytics/postgresql-42.2.23.jar ./postgresql-42.2.23.jar

# Set the local path for the JDBC driver
jdbc_jar_path = "./postgresql-42.2.23.jar"

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = f'--driver-class-path {jdbc_jar_path} --jars {jdbc_jar_path} pyspark-shell'

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PySpark with PostgreSQL") \
    .config("spark.jars", jdbc_jar_path) \
    .getOrCreate()

url = "jdbc:postgresql://my_url/my_path"
properties = {
    "user": "my_user",
    "password": "my_password",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}

query = "(SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(when_ at time zone 'PST') = '2024-06-17')"

# Read data from PostgreSQL
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=query, properties=properties)

I got this error: An error occurred while calling o335.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
enter image description here
